# Duplicate layout IDs returning as -1 after view replacement

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

**Short Story:**
I have a layout "layout.xml", which gets replaced by another layout "success.xml" after a successful web request. Both layouts have an `ImageView` that provides the backgrounds to the layouts. These 2 backgrounds both need to be the same, and both are dependent on a user preference.

**Longer Story:** This all happens in a `Fragmnet` with an `AsyncTask` replacing the contentView with "success.xml" in `onPostExecute` after the web request. This happens as follows:

```
View view = getView();
view = null;
view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.success, null);
```

What I tried to do is give both `ImageView`s the following `android:id="@+id/background_image"` and then call

```
ImageView background = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.background_image);
background.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg1);
```

This background-setting works for the initial view (layout.xml), but on trying to change to "success.xml", I get a NullPointException because `background` is null.

I've checked and the View's id is set to -1 while the original view's `background_image` id is set to something sensible and valid.

I've also tried setting the second view's background id like this: `android:id="@id/background_image"`, i.e. without the '+', but still no luck.

The added complication is that it's not just 2 layouts, but about 5 that I need to do this for, so it would be really handy to recycle view id's.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: +1 for your short and long story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code for replacing the fragment's view will not do what you want, the original view will remain the same as you change only a reference to that view and not the actual object.

To replace the view of the fragment with the new layout you could have another `ViewGroup`(for example a `FrameLayout`) in the basic layout (`layout.xml`) wrapping your current content(don't forget to give it an id) of `layouts.xml`(as I understand this is the basic layout). Then, when it's time to replace the layout you could simply do:

```
// remove the current content
((ViewGroup) getView().findViewById(R.id.yourWrapperLayout)).removeAllViews();
// add the new content
View.inflate(context, R.layout.success, ((ViewGroup) getView().findViewById(R.id.yourWrapperLayout)));
```

You could avoid adding an extra layout if, by any chance, all your five layouts have the same type for the root view(like a `LinearLayout` etc). In this case you would use the same code as above but you'll modify the other layouts file to use a `merge` tag. Also, you'll be looking for the id of the root in the `layout.xml` layout into which you'll add the content of the other files.

Then you could have the same ids, but you'll have to reinitialize any reference to the views(meaning that you'll have to search for the view again if you store a reference to the view(like a `Button` field in the fragment class)).

Comment: I'm onto about the third way of doing this. I've tried using wrapper layouts and replacing the views like that but I was having issues aligning the views correctly. Why can I not simply do this: `((ViewGroup) getView()).removeAllViews();` and then `View.inflate(con, R.layout.faults_track_result, (ViewGroup) getView());`? I've just tried what I've just written but getView() then returns a `NoSaveStateFrameLayout`.

Comment: @MikeT You can't do it like that(see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676399/whats-the-nosavestateframelayout ). The correct way is to have a wrapper layout, search for it using it's own id and attach the new View to it(like in my answer).

Comment: It's a little hard to accept this. Everything was working fine. My layouts change as they're meant to. All I needed to do was find an `ImageView` in the layout that was already there displaying correctly. I really don't want to have to restructure ~12 layouts in my app just to find a view

Comment: @MikeT I'm not sure I follow what is the problem. The layouts change but you can't find the views? Everything was working fine?

Comment: Yes, the layouts successfully change and the buttons work on them and everything, but when I try findViewById on the ImageView, it returns `null` and if I check using Eclipse debug tools, the ImageView's id is set to -1

Comment: @MikeT I don't see how that would happen if the other views from the layout work. I actually tested with an `ImageView` so things should work with no problems.

Comment: I'm stumped. The success view looks fine, except that `mId` of the ImageView is always -1, even if I add a unique id to it

Comment: @MikeT Can you share a little more code regarding that fragment? Maybe the two problematic layouts file as well?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18283/discussion-between-mike-t-and-luksprog)