# Force call onCreateView on Fragment

Tags: android, fragment

My application is crashing quite a bit after using a task killer because apparently the view is removed, making getView() return null.
How can I force the fragment to re-create it's view if it happens to be null?

Comment: Your entire process is gone "after using a task killer". You have some other problem.

Comment: My getView() is returning a NoSaveStateFrameLayout after the task kill. Any idea?

Comment: That is perfectly normal AFAIK: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9440816/115145

Answer (score 1):

You can use newInstance method to get you fragment as static.

```
public static ProfileMainView newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        Fragment fragment = new YourFragmentView();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

and then make your own view this way. you need to check whether your view is null or not. If it's null, make view again. If it's not, just use it. I hope it to be helpful for you.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(view == null){
             // Make your view here by inflater or whatever
        }
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this every way imaginable, what you posted above does not work. It doesn't matter how many times you call onCreateView() it will never update.